# iphone - discovering the UITableViewCell given the cell.imageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView inserted sideways (rotated 90 degrees) in a view. This table has images. I need to implement the swipe method in a cell to allow deleting it, but as the table is sideways, I cannot use the table default swipe delete mechanism, or the delete icon would appear sideways and worst, microscopic, because the table is small.

So, I have to implement my own swipe method for the cell.

To do so, I have added the UISwipeGestureRecognizer gesture recognizer to each cell's imageView. When this method fires, I receive the cell's imageView on the handle method.

So, when a swipe happens on a cell.imageView the method handleSwipe: is fired...

```
- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
```

Inside this method I can easily get the cell.imageView, by doing [gestureRecognizer view], but how do I obtain a reference to the cell itself?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *handleSwipe:* method, try the following code.

```
UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *) [gestureRecognizer view];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[imgView superview] superview];
```

I guess this will work.

Comment: Thanks, you were almost there. Xcode was giving me this error: " "warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct UITableViewCell *'... I modified your last line to UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[imgView superview] superview]; and it worked.


"

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this might be to subclass the `UIImageView` and add an index property to this subclass. Then you can call on that property to see which cell that `UIImageView` belonged to.